# Which information of a VMware image can be monitored from the host?

Tags: virtualization, monitoring, vmware

I run a Linux virtual machine on my Windows 10 host.

What information (e.g. https traffic) can be monitored from the host?
Is it safe to browse on a virtual machine that uses the host device's network adapter (regarding privacy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which information (e.g. https traffic) can be monitored from the host? Is it safe to browse on a virtual machine that uses the host device's network adapter (regarding privacy)?

The host has full access to peek at the memory of the VM. It can read any secret crypto keys from the memory of the VM, and trivially decrypt all TLS traffic if it wants to. It can interecept all communication at will, and inject traffic into the networking stack of the VM.

You can't use a VM to protect against a rogue host.

Comment: that is true, in the general case, possible worth noting that there are implementations of Virtualization that are designed to protect guest VMs from malicious software on the host (e.g. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/data-center-security/what-are-shielded-vms-in-windows-server-2016-hyper-v/ba-p/372179)